# Why use "le" in "se le oyo"?

Tags: objetos-indirectos, reflexivos

What is the use of "**le**" in the following sentence:

> La única vez que **se le oyó** un comentario nostálgico fue a propósito de un piano de cola.

I think `oirse` in this case means `was heard`. Is the `le` used to emphazise `was heard from him/her`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're so close. It actually means "from him/her", but it is not empahisis, because it is not repeating any information, but adding it for the first time.

If you said

> Se oyó un comentario

That would mean `A comment was heard`, as you correctly point out, which is nice because "se" is indeed a difficult word.

But "le" is adding relevant information. It replaces an indirect object. It's relating the coment to that "him/her"

> Se le oyó un comentario a él = A comment was heard **from him**

(same with her).